Computer computation of the first Galois cohomology of a $p$-adic torus?
Let $T\subset {\rm GL}(N,{\mathbb Q})$ be an $n$-dimensional  ${\mathbb Q}$-torus
given by its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}\subset \mathfrak{gl}(N,{\mathbb Q})$.
I want to compute, in some sense explicitly, the cocharacter group
$$M=X_*(T):=X_*(T_{\overline{\mathbb Q}})={\rm Hom}({\mathbb G}_{{\rm m},\overline{\mathbb Q}}, T_{\overline {\mathbb Q}}); $$
of course, it is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}^n$.
The absolute Galois group ${\rm Gal}(\overline {\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Q})$ naturally acts on $M$.
Consider the effective Galois group
$$\Theta:={\rm im}\big[{\rm Gal}(\overline {\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Q})\to {\rm GL}(M)\big].$$
We obtain a finite group $\Theta\subseteq {\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$.

Question 1. How can I compute $\Theta\subseteq {\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ using computer?

Let $L/{\mathbb Q}$ be the finite Galois extension corresponding to the kernel
$$\ker\big[{\rm Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Q})\to \Theta\big].$$
Then ${\rm Gal}(L/{\mathbb Q})=\Theta$.
Let $V_{\mathbb Q}=\{\infty,2,3,5,7,11,\dots\}$ denote the set of places of ${\mathbb Q}$,
and let $V_L$ denote the set of places of $L$.
We have a natural surjective map
$$V_L\to V_{\mathbb Q}\,,$$
and $\Theta$ acts on the fibers of this map via the action on $L$.
Let $p\in V_{\mathbb Q}$  be a prime number, and let $v\in V_L$ be a place of $L$ over $p$.
Consider the decomposition group $\Theta_v={\rm Stab}_\Theta(v)$.
It is determined by $p$ uniquely up to conjugation.

Question 2.  How can I compute the subgroup $\Theta_v\subseteq\Theta\subseteq {\rm GL}(M)= {\rm GL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ using computer?

Assuming that I have computed $M$ and $\Theta_v\subseteq{\rm GL}(M)$, I can compute using computer  the first Galois cohomology group
$$ H^1({\mathbb Q}_p,T)\cong(M_{\Theta_v})_{\rm Tors}\,,$$
the torsion subgroup of the group of co-invariants of $\Theta_v$ in $M$.
